# How can a device that has a 16 bit depth be sending an integer value bigger than 2^16?

Tags: microcontroller

I have an ESP32 setup as an A2DP sink. It uses a SBC audio codec which provides sampling rates from 44.1kHz to 48kHz at a bit depth of 16 bits. [SBC Tech Spec](https://www.headphonesty.com/2020/03/bluetooth-audio-codecs-explained/)

To me this means that the ESP32 is only capable of sending integer values up to 65536, but since its signed, so actually its from -32,768 to +32,768.

On the receiving end I am using a [STM32H7](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753zi.html) and during my decoding sessions I noticed the buffer that I am using to receive the ESP32 samples are much greater that of 2^16, what gives?

**The datatype of the array I am using to store the ESP32 samples is an int.**
and its called **int RxBuff_bluetooth[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOrmt.png)];**

Example of a snapshot in debug:

[image]

PICTURE OF I2S BUS:

[image]

CODE:

```
// ------------------------ INCLUDES --------------//

#include "supportFunctions.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "I2S.h"
#include "Clock.h"
#include "I2S.h"
#include "Interrupt.h"
#include "UART.h"

// ------------------------ GLOBAL VARIABLES ----------//

int RxBuff_inline[4]; // incoming Audio Signal (inline)
int TxBuff_inline[4]; // Outgoing Audio Signal (inline)
int RxBuff_bluetooth[4];
int TxBuff_bluetooth[4];

float * IIR_Coeffs;
float * IIR_State;
float inSample_inline_L[2]; // Goes to RxBuff -> inSample
float inSample_inline_R[2];
float outSample_inline_L[2]; // Goes to RxBuff -> inSample
float outSample_inline_R[2];

float inSample_bluetooth_L[2]; // Goes to RxBuff -> inSample
float inSample_bluetooth_R[2];
float outSample_bluetooth_L[2]; // Goes to outSamples -> TxBuff
float outSample_bluetooth_R[2];
float inputcompensator = 1.0;

uint8_t inLine_Rx_Complete_Callback = 0; // When half the audio samples arrive
uint8_t inLine_Rx_Half_Callback = 0; // When the full audio samples arrive
uint8_t bluetooth_Rx_Complete_Callback = 0; // When half the audio samples arrive
uint8_t bluetooth_Rx_Half_Callback = 0; // When the full audio samples arrive
uint8_t UART_Rx_Callback = 0; // When STM32 Receives a UART command
uint8_t highShelfEnable = 0; // High Shelf Filters are in use
uint8_t lowShelfEnable = 0; //  Low Shelf Filters are in use
uint8_t ESP_to_STM32[1]; // Buffer to store UART commands from ESP to STM32
uint8_t volumePacket = 0; // Volume Packet is being received
uint8_t volumeCurrent = 50; //Current Volume
uint8_t sourceMode = 0;

arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 audioStream_L; // Creates a ARM strut
arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 audioStream_R;
IIR Filters; // Creates a structure holding all EQ Filters
pState stateVariables;

int main(void) {

  // ----------------------------------------------- INIT ------------------------------- //

  init_Clock();
  init_I2S_Inline(RxBuff_inline, TxBuff_inline);
  init_I2S_Bluetooth(RxBuff_bluetooth, TxBuff_bluetooth);
  init_UART(ESP_to_STM32);
  init_IIRFilter(IIR_Coeffs, IIR_State, &Filters);
  init_Interrupt();

  while (1) {

    // -------------------------------------------- SOURCE SELECTOR ---------------------- //

    if (inLine_Rx_Half_Callback == OK) {

      prcoess_inline_halfSample(RxBuff_inline, TxBuff_inline, inSample_inline_L, inSample_inline_R, outSample_inline_L, outSample_inline_R, volumeScale, volumeCurrent, &audioStream_L, &audioStream_R, inputcompensator);
      inLine_Rx_Half_Callback = RESET;

    } else if (inLine_Rx_Complete_Callback == OK) {

      process_inline_CompleteSample(RxBuff_inline, TxBuff_inline, inSample_inline_L, inSample_inline_R, outSample_inline_L, outSample_inline_R, volumeScale, volumeCurrent, &audioStream_L, &audioStream_R, inputcompensator);
      inLine_Rx_Complete_Callback = RESET;

  }  else if (bluetooth_Rx_Half_Callback == OK) {

      prcoess_bluetooth_halfSample(RxBuff_bluetooth, TxBuff_bluetooth, inSample_bluetooth_L, inSample_bluetooth_R, outSample_bluetooth_L, outSample_bluetooth_R, volumeScale, volumeCurrent, &audioStream_L, &audioStream_R, inputcompensator);
      bluetooth_Rx_Half_Callback = RESET;

    } else if (bluetooth_Rx_Complete_Callback) {

      prcoess_bluetooth_CompleteSample(RxBuff_bluetooth, TxBuff_bluetooth, inSample_bluetooth_L, inSample_bluetooth_R, outSample_bluetooth_L, outSample_bluetooth_R, volumeScale, volumeCurrent, &audioStream_L, &audioStream_R, inputcompensator);
      bluetooth_Rx_Complete_Callback = RESET;

    } else if (UART_Rx_Callback == OK) {

      processUartPacket(ESP_to_STM32, &volumePacket, &volumeCurrent, &audioStream_L, &audioStream_R, Filters, &inputcompensator, &sourceMode, stateVariables);
      UART_Rx_Callback = RESET;

    }

  }

}

void DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF3)) != 0) {
    DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF3;
    UART_Rx_Callback = 1;
  }
}

void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0) {
      DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
      inLine_Rx_Complete_Callback = 1;

  } else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0) {
    DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
    inLine_Rx_Half_Callback = 1;

  }
}

void DMA1_Stream4_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (((DMA1 -> HISR) & (DMA_HISR_TCIF4)) != 0) {
      DMA1 -> HIFCR |= DMA_HIFCR_CTCIF4;
      bluetooth_Rx_Complete_Callback = 1;

  } else if (((DMA1 -> HISR) & (DMA_HISR_HTIF4)) != 0) {
    DMA1 -> HIFCR |= DMA_HIFCR_CHTIF4;
    bluetooth_Rx_Half_Callback = 1;

  }
}
```

I2S & DMA Configuration: Of STM32H7

```
void init_I2S_Bluetooth(int * RxBuff_bluetooth, int * TxBuff_bluetooth) {

    //Setting Clock for 48MHz
        //N = 122
        //P = 16
        //M = 10
        //FRACT = 7209

        // RCC_PLL2DIVR
        // MASKING:
        /*RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2;
        RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2_DIV16; // P
        RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2_MULT122; // N

        // RCC_PLLCKSELR
        // MASKING:
        RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_DIV10; // M

        // RCC_PLL2FRACR
        // MASKING:
        RCC -> PLL2FRACR &= ~RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN2;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> PLL2FRACR |= RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN_7209; // FRAC

        // RCC_PLLCFGR
        // MASKING:
        RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE_4_8;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL_192_836;
        RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;

        // RCC_CR
        // MASKING:
        RCC -> CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
        // WAITING:
        while (((RCC -> CR) & (RCC_CR_PLL2RDY)) == 0){};*/

        // ENALBING CLOCKS

        // RCC_AHB4ENR
        // MASKING:
        RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
        RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;

        // WRITING:
        RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
        RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;

        // RCC_APB2ENR
        // MASKING:
        RCC ->APB1LENR &= ~RCC_APB1LENR_SPI3EN;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> APB1LENR |= RCC_APB1LENR_SPI3EN;

        // CHANGING CLOCKS OF PERIPHERALS
        // RCC_D2CCIP1R
        // MASKING;
       /* RCC -> D2CCIP1R &= ~RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL;
        // WRITING:
        RCC -> D2CCIP1R |=  RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL_PLL2_P_CK;*/

        // CHANGING GPIO PINS TO ALETERNATIVE
            // GPIOx_MODER
            // MASKING
            GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE10; //PC10: SCLK
            GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE11; //PC11: MISO
            GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE12; //PC12: MOSI
            GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE15; //PA15: LRCLK
            //GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7;  //PC07: MCLK

            // WRITING:
            GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE10_ALT; //PC10: SCLK
            GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE11_ALT; //PC11: MISO
            GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE12_ALT; //PC12: MOSI
            GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE15_ALT; //PA15: LRCLK
            //GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE7_ALT; //PC07: MCLK


            //SETTING ALT FUNCTIONS TO PINS
            // GPIOx_AFRL
            // MASKING:
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] &= ~GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL10_AF6; //PC10: SCLK
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] &= ~GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL11_AF6; //PC11: MISO
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] &= ~GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL12_AF6; //PC12: MOSI
            GPIOA -> AFR[1] &= ~GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL15_AF6; //PA15: LRCLK
            //GPIOC -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_AF6;  //PA07: MCLK

            // WRITING;
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] |= GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL10_AF6; //PC10: SCLK
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] |= GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL11_AF6; //PC11: MISO
            GPIOC -> AFR[1] |= GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL12_AF6; //PC12: MOSI
            GPIOA -> AFR[1] |= GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL15_AF6; //PA15: LRCLK
            //GPIOC -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_AF6;  //PA7:  MCLK


            // ENABLING DMA1
                // RCC_AHB1ENR
                // MASKING:
                RCC -> AHB1ENR &= ~RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
                // WRITING:
                RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;

                // MASKING:
                  DMAMUX1_Channel4 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
                  DMAMUX1_Channel5 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
                  // WRITING:
                  DMAMUX1_Channel4 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI3_Rx; //Rx
                  DMAMUX1_Channel5 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_SPI3_Tx; //Tx

                  // DMA1_Stream0_CR
                        // DMA1_Stream1_CR
                        // MASKING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
                        // WRITING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_P_TO_M;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_M_TO_P;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;

                        // DMA_SxNDTR
                        // WRITING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> NDTR = 0x4;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> NDTR = 0x4;

                        // DMA_SxPAR
                        // WRITING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> PAR = (int) & SPI3 -> RXDR;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> PAR = (int) & SPI3 -> TXDR;

                        // DMA_SxM0AR
                        // WRITING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> M0AR = (int) RxBuff_bluetooth;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> M0AR = (int) TxBuff_bluetooth;

                        // DMA_SxCR
                        // WRITING:
                        DMA1_Stream4 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;
                        DMA1_Stream5 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

                        // Setting up the SPI/I2S Peripheral
                           // MASKING:
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATLEN;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CHLEN;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD;
                           SPI3 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
                           SPI3 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
                           SPI3 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_FTHLV;

                           // WRITING:
                           //SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
                           //SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD_MULT2;
                           //SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV_2;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV_I2S;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATALEN_32BIT;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_FIXCH;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL_FALL_RISE;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD_I2STAND;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CHNEL_32BIT_WIDE;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG_SLAVE_FULLDUPLEX;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD_I2S_PCM_MODE;
                           SPI3 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT_LAlign;
                           //SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_CFG1_FTHLV_2_Data;
                           SPI3 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
                           SPI3 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
                          /* SPI3 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
                           SPI3 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART;*/


}
```

I2S Configuration of ESP32:

```
i2s_config_t i2s_config = {

        .mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX,                                  // Only TX
        .sample_rate = 44100,
        .bits_per_sample = 16,
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,                           //2-channels
        .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S,
        .dma_buf_count = 6,
        .dma_buf_len = 60,
        .intr_alloc_flags = 0,        
        .use_apll = true,                                        //Default interrupt priority
        .tx_desc_auto_clear = true                                              //Auto clear tx descriptor on underflow
    };
```

Comment: It isn't. You're interpreting what you receive as more than 16 bits. Quite possibly, two received samples are packed into an Int, and you are forgetting to unpack them into Shorts. (There are other possibilities : the device datasheet and user guide will tell you how data is packed.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, ill look into it thank you

Comment: You've posted variations of this same issue *way* too many times.  This is what, try #7?

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is the second time you posted with no context to the question. If you want to have an agurment about the "Try #7" Lets, please explain to me how is this the same issue as the others? Ill be waiting

Comment: @ChrisStratton If you read the answer to the previous "6 tries" as an example, you would have noticed its a misunderstanding of the hardware I am currently using. You are assuming I haven't read the documentation. I spent countless of nights trying to decipher the documentation. I post in the STM32 forums first before I go here. But when the guys over at there say the reference manual explains it poorly I come here for a more detail answer. Yes, sure the topics are related to I2S in some shape or form ill give you that, but every question is different from one another, just go take a lookise.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The funniest thing is, I am hearing you. You posted in my last comment to get a logic analyzer, you know what I did, I got one. I been using it for 16 hours straight now and I am not seeing anything that can help me resolve some of the issues I have been experiencing, what I learned from it the "CHLEN" register changes the SLCK frequency, nice. What I am getting from you Is I can't post questions that under the same umbrella anymore. Sure I posted a lot of I2S questions but they're a lot of moving parts in the I2S domain, at least for me.

Comment: You may have a logic analyzer, but you're not yet sending known bit patterns which could give you a known basis for what you should expect to see or receive.  By comparing what you send to what you see on the wire and what you receive, you can understand the ultimate configuration/usage/data-manipulation mistakes at the heart of your difficulties.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Trying to setup it up as we speak. I think thats a fantastic idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is again a neat feature of I2S bus. You can send any bits worth of data as long as it is smaller than or equal to the length of the data frame. Typical data frame sizes are only 16, 24 and 32 bit per channel. Data is sent MSB first so devices wanting to transmit or receive only 16 bits of data in a longer frame, it will just ignore or leave the LSBs it does not need to zero, or undefined.

Another thing is that your STM32 can be configured to receive 16 bits data and expand that to 32 bit data in memory. It migh be even required to expand 24-bit frames to 32 bits of data, even if only 16 bits are transferred over a 24 bit frame. The exact details of I2S peripheral is in the reference manual, and the errata lists further limitations which modes are not possible for some reason. The peripheral and DMA transfer can be used to do all kinds of conversions on the data as well. So it is also possible that the 16-bit samples that come in are actually stored correctly in the buffer, but they are just interpreted wrong.

The buffer is defined to be an array of integers, and so your integers are 32-bit. There might be one 16-bit sample expanded to 32-bit, or there might be two 16-bit samples stored in the 32-bit integer. It is up to the configuration of I2S and DMA modules which your code does not reveal.

So even if 16 bit data only has values between 0 and 65535 or -32768 to +32767 they can already be expanded and MSB-aligned to be to fill the 16 MSBs of 32-bit data and least significant 16 bits are simply zeroes.

Comment: I see what you mean, that make sense. Still a little confusing because in a STM32 it has two registers called "DATALEN" and "CHLEN". What I could gather is that datalen can be 16/24/32 and CHLEN changes the clock cycle depending whats set such as 16 or 32. So CHLEN seems like the "data frame" in your answer then whats datalen? why would I need to set that if the data being received can be accepted with a high CHLEN setting. I gotta double check if its not packing L and R onto a 32 bit integer

Comment: If it was two 16 bits packed into a 32 bit, how would I unwrap it. Kinda confused with the Left align and MSB format going on. Should I shift  it or should I & it with 0xFF's. Ill update the main post to fill out the missing blanks (The I2S and DMA configuration)

Comment: Change the buffer to be array of uint16 types?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the values reported by the debugger, *int* must be 32-bits in this compiler. If you explicitly define their variable sizes, issues like this can be avoided. Some of your other variables are defined as uint8_t; is there a reason you didn't define these variables as uint16_t?

Comment: Variables that have uint8_t declared is simply because those variables are only going to be receiving data of 2^8

Comment: @Leoc  In this case you defined that variable to be 32 bits. This has nothing to do with the hardware, it is a choice that you made.  If the data is really 16 bit, then the second half of the 32 bits will be blank or will actually contain the next sample.  If it is really 32 bit, then you should check the documentation to see what the second half represents (maybe it is a L/R pair of samples?). You can probably get a good idea from just looking at the data.

Comment: Correct variables are defined as 32 bits by user choice. I am fairly new to this and from experience can't tell just by looking at the data, I have updated the main post with pictures of the I2S bus decode if you wanna take a look at that?

Comment: First, define the variables as 16-bit. But, that may not solve the issue. You also need to make sure that the DMA is moving 16-bits at a time.

Comment: I see, however should it not matter if the DMA is set to 32 bits as it will still transfer the whole 16 bit context? Let say the ESP32 can only transfer 16 bits of data, so 16 bits travel down the I2S bus let say 0x1516 , the DMA gets triggered and transfers the 0x1516 because its capacity is 32 bits and 16 bits < 32 bits. This raises another question however, does the DMA know the proper endianess ?